# Push a new project to github without visiting github.com using intellij

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I created a project in intellij. I enabled git, wrote some code. Committed what I wrote.

I want to push this project to github. Note that github dont have an idea about what I am doing since I did not cretate and clone a project in the github first.

How can i push this project to github?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA has integration with GitHub.

From the documentation:

[Share a project on GitHub](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manage-projects-hosted-on-github.html#share-on-GitHub)

1. Open the project you want to share.
2. From the main menu, choose **Git | GitHub | Share Project on GitHub**.

If you have already registered your GitHub account in IntelliJ IDEA, connection will be established using these credentials.

If you have not registered your account in IntelliJ IDEA, the Login to GitHub dialog opens. Specify your access token or request a new one with your login and password.

3. When connection to GitHub has been established, the **Share Project on GitHub** dialog opens. Specify the new repository name, the name of the remote , and enter a description of your project.

You can select the **Private** option if you do not want to allow public access to your repository for other GitHub users.

4. Click **Share** to initiate a new repository and upload project sources to it.